# thread join vs. lock ( or semaphore ) in java

Tags: java, multithreading

1 The answer for the question, "How can we make sure that the threads executes in a particular order", is using join() method appropriately ( ref: http://beginnersbook.com/2015/03/thread-join-method-in-java-with-example/).

2 A question in 15.5 Call in order in CiCt 6th edition below.

Suppose we have the following code:

```
public class Foo {
   public Foo() { ... }
   public void first() { ... }
   public void second() { ... }
   public void third() { ... }
}
```

"The same instance of Foo will be passed to three different threads. ThreadA will call first,
threadB will call second, and threadC will call third.
Design a mechanism to ensure that
first is called before second and second is called before third."

This book provide two solutions: 1) lock(unlock) and 2) Semaphore

Question: I'm wondering why this book doesn't describe join() as one of solutions  for this question.

My understanding is about the difference between join() and lock(unlock)/semapore is

> join() is waiting until one thread is completed and then start.
>
> lock(unlock) or semaphore only guarantees order of staring threads
> but not waiting until another thread is completed?

My understanding is correct or not?

Could someone clarify the difference?

Also I'd like to know the case cases for join(), lock() and semaphore in real world projects or practical examples.

Comment: What if the thread does something else after calling the function?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, could you write the full name of the book?

Comment: Worst. Thread Homework. Ever.  The whole point of threads is to be able to do things _concurrently_.  If you ever find yourself in a real situation (i.e., not a school assignment) where certain things need to be done in a certain order, then the _best_ way to make sure that happens---best by far---is to do them all in a single thread.

Comment: If you ask me this samplescenario is rather clumsy. It is used to motivate some of those primitives but is not a good fit for any of them. Why for example would you use 3 threads if you can use one to execute the 3 methods perfectly in order with no inter-thread communication at all. For that reason I would not worry much to apply join() - it can be used however it is risky as it will be the wrong primitive. Better use executors and wait for the result (or use callbacks to submit the next step).

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't make any sense to ask about the *difference* between `thread.join()` and `lock.lock()`/`lock.unlock()`.  They are used for completely different purposes.

Use `thread.join()` to make one thread wait for another thread to die.  One use case for `join()` would be a program that performs some lengthy calculation.  The main thread could create as many *worker threads* as the computer has CPUs and assign each worker to do one independent part of the calculation.  Then the main thread could wait for all of the workers to finish their tasks by calling `thread1.join()`, `thread2.join()`, ...  And then after they all were done, the main thread could combine the partial results produced by each thread into a final result

---

Use `lock.lock()` and `lock.unlock()` to prevent threads from *interfering* with one another by preventing them from accessing the same shared data at the same time.  This use-case is called *mutual exclusion*, or *mutex* for short.

The Java language offers one mechanism for mutual exclusion---`synchronized` blocks---and newer editions of the Java standard library offer another mechanism---`java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock`.  I could go on about how and when and why to use them, but you'd be better off just reading the tutorial:  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html

---

Semaphores are yet another different thing.  Semaphores are an old idea that come from a time before computer had hardware support for thread synchronization.  The main reason they still exist today is because lots of old code and textbooks use them/talk about them.  You can use semaphores for mutual exclusion, but you can use them for other purposes too.

IMO the best way to understand semaphores is to first understand blocking queues:  A Semaphore effectively is a blocking queue of virtual *permits*, where "permits" are indistinguishable, informationless tokens.  Since permits carry no information, they don't actually need to exist.  A semaphore just keeps count of how many permits are "in" it.

There is nothing you can do with a Semaphore that you can't also do with a blocking queue of empty Objects, which is why I say, learn blocking queues first if you have a choice.